# Entity Framework does not save object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

Entity Framework does not save object. Next code runs without any error, but changes are not affected in DB.

```
using (MedDbEntities me = new MedDbEntities())
            {
                Patients p = new Patients();
                p.lastName = _uc.lastNameTextBox.Text;
                p.firstName = _uc.firstNameTextBox.Text;
                p.middleName = _uc.middleNameTextBox.Text;
                p.sex = 0;
                if (_uc.sexComboBox.SelectedText.Equals("ч"))
                    p.sex = 1;
                if (_uc.sexComboBox.SelectedText.Equals("ж"))
                    p.sex = 2;
                p.birthday = _uc.birthdayDateTimePicker.Value;

                me.AddToPatients(p);
                me.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Please, advise where can be problem.

Comment: What steps have you taken to troubleshoot and what were the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your Db?

An attached-file database is copied (overwritten) on each build.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to do SaveChanges inside of AddToPatients method ?
Inside of that method you sould have something like this :

```
_db.Patients.AddObject(patient);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the ObjectStateManager to change the state of the object to Updated because it is a newly instantiated entity

```
MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

Product product = new Product();
product.Title = "My New Product";

db.AddToProduct(product);
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(product, System.Data.EntityState.Updated);
db.SaveChanges();
```