# entity saveChanges not updating database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am following a tutorial using entity framework in C# and having a number of issues.

My first issue is that I could not access the .Load() or addObject() methods through my entity.  After much searching I found this which so far has seemed to help:

[.Net Framework 4.5 AddObject() does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523512/net-framework-4-5-addobject-does-not-appear)

After continuing on with the tutorial I am now having an issue when trying to save a new record to the database.

```
        using (NORTHWNDEntities ctx = new NORTHWNDEntities())
        {

            var customers = from c in ctx.Customers.Include("Orders")
                            where c.City == "London"
                            select c;

            //adds to customer
            Customer newCustomer = new Customer { CustomerID = "JoeN", City = "London", ContactName = "Joe N", CompanyName = "Acme" };
            ctx.Customers.AddObject(newCustomer);

            ctx.SaveChanges();


            foreach (Customer customer in customers)
            {
                //customer.Orders.Load();
                Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} has {1} orders {2}", customer.ContactName, customer.Orders.Count(), customer.Phone);
            }
```

When my code runs it displays the newly added customer however the database is not updated.

I have tried the suggested solutions on [Entity Framework does not save object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381932/entity-framework-does-not-save-object)
I don't have the addTo method in my entity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework does not save object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381932/entity-framework-does-not-save-object)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Create` on the DbContext is more appropriate and may resolve your issue:

```
Customer newCustomer = ctx.Customers.Create();
newCustomer.CustomerID = "JoeN";
..etc, etc
ctx.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This didn't work either.  It behaved in the same way as the addObject method.

Comment: Make sure no exceptions are thrown by using a Try/Catch, and also try profiling the database to see if/what sql statements are actually hitting it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ctx.Customers.AddObject(newCustomer);` how about trying `ctx.Customers.Attach(newCustomer);`

Comment: I thought .attach was only for updating existing entries?

Comment: I deleted everything and started again for the forth time and all of a sudden my table is now updating. I am going with the create method from above as it meant I didn't need to delete the .tt files.  Thank you for you help.